# Configure Cisco 871W to connect to VyperVPN

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, cisco-vpn

How can I configure my Cisco router to router certain traffic (IP or domain-based) through a VyperVPN connection?

VyperVPN uses IPSec:

http://www.giganews.com/vyprvpn/setup/mac/l2tp.html

Sample configuration is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with Cisco IOS, although I'm struggling to find an IOS-XE solution.

First you need so set up a VPDN client:

```
vpdn-group <profile-name>
  description <whatever>
  request-dialin
   protocol pptp
   pool-member 1
  initiate-to ip <vyprvpn-ip>
  source-ip <your-public-ip>
```

If you're already using dialer pool 1, choose a unique number.

Then you need to set up your dialer interface:

```
interface Dialer1
 description <whatever>
 ip address negotiated
 ip nat outside # if needed
 encapsulation ppp
 dialer pool 1 # must match pool-member in vpdn
 dialer idle-timeout 0
 dialer string 1
 dialer persistent
 dialer vpdn
 no cdp enable
 ppp mtu adaptive
 ppp encrypt mppe auto
 ppp authentication ms-chap-v2 callin optional
 ppp chap hostname <vyprvpn-username>
 ppp chap password 0 <vyprvpn-password>
```

Since dialers are always up/up, you can check the state of your VPDN tunnel with:

```
#show vpdn session

%No active L2TP tunnels

PPTP Session Information Total tunnels 2 sessions 2

LocID RemID TunID Intf    Username      State   Last Chg Uniq ID
1289  0     27207 Vi7                   wt-tun  never    0
18761 217   32422 Vi4     pptpd         estabd  03:51:25 0
```

The "estabd" session above is using the virtual interface Vi4.  Check that the dialer interface is bound to it:

```
show int dialer 1 | inc Virtual-Access
Virtual-Access4 is up, line protocol is up
```

You should also have an IP address on the dialer.

Routing (and possibly NATing) is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the cisco route certain traffic to a particular host (in this case the machine running  VyperVPN) is relatively straight-forward.  On the Cisco router you would run a command of the form in config mode : 'ip route dst-ip dst-mask ip-of-VyperVPN-host'.

Getting the machine running VyperVPN to accept this traffic and route it through the tunnel varies depending on your OS.  For example on a linux system you need to enable ip forwarding using the sysctl command as root : 'sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1'.